# Install Windows Defender on Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-defender

I've been trying to install the Microsoft anti-virus but Microsoft Security Essentials does not work and I can't find Defender to install.

From what I know you CAN NOT use Microsoft Security Essentials with Windows 8/Server 2012. I've done some searching for Windows Defender Download but I can't fine a link anywhere. How can I get this installed?

Comment: What have you tried? What errors are you getting? What do you mean "MSE does not work"? Please be more specific and **update your question with that information** (I.e. don't add that info to comments)

Comment: Looks like MS's documentation is incorrect according to @PeterHahndorf - so hopefully since he is familiar with the system, he can help you out.

Comment: Windows Defender is built into Windows 8 you can either enable it or disable it.  There is nothing to download, its the exact same engine as MSE, MSE won't be on other platforms.

Comment: There's a [workaround here](http://superuser.com/q/523119/3186)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft is not supporting Windows Defender on Server 2012, it is recommended you use a 3rd party solution or the corporate IT branded version of Windows Defender called [Endpoint Protection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh508836.aspx) which is bundled in to System Center 2012. Licenses for System Center 2012 cost about [$1,000 to $3,000](https://www.google.com/search?q=System%20Center%202012&tbm=shop).